# xcode does not copy latest file to .app(package content)

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using xocde 5, it looks like does not update the latest edited data file(for exmaple a.data) to

/Users/zw/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/X.0/Applications/55EF423F-A662-42E1-810B-7276AD95798C/myapp.app

I have to copy the data file to the .app manually.

or have to clean and rebuild whole project.

I check the data file, it has targeted to project

Your comment welcome

Comment: Resource copying isn't as good when running against simulator, if that is critical you could write a custom build phase script that would find the app location at simulator directory and remove it during the builds. It should work better with devices though.

Comment: but it suddenly does not work, it worked well brefore

Comment: Yeah it usually works, I wonder if you did any changes at Spotlight settings or system preferences in general. Anyway, when you have somewhat dynamic bundle content it might be a good idea to ensure it is copied: how about instead of removing the app folder you add a script (build phase) that would copy content of your special folder to `"$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH"` (use `ditto` for that).

Comment: It works!!! please set to answer, I will accept it, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make sure the critical data is copied to the app bundle when it is somehow dynamic you can add a build phase script that will copy content of the special directory to the app bundle:

```
ditto ./MyPrefixResources/ "$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH"
```